# Condition for submodularity of multilabel pairwise potentials

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, computer-vision

According to slide 5 [here](https://www.ipam.ucla.edu/publications/gc2008/gc2008_7732.pdf) the condition for submodularity for a multilabel pairwise energy function is

```
for $\alpha < \beta$ and $\alpha' < \beta'$,
    $f(\alpha, \alpha') + f(\beta, \beta') <= f(\alpha, \beta') + f(\alpha', \beta)$
```

How does that inequality imply submodularity? I can understand how the inequality for the binary label case implies submodularity (marginal gain of picking an element in a set is higher when we didn't have any element initially), but how should one interpret the multilabel case?

Comment: the link appears to be missing, is alpha prime the complement of alpha? could this be the definition F(A) + F(B)  >= F(AUB) - f(A\cap B)